# Checking if a Polygon contains MultiPoint in Shapely returns unexpected results

Tags: python, shapely

Can you explain the behaviour of Shapely `contains` method? Why is the first result below `False` and the second result `True`?

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, MultiPoint

poly = Polygon([[0,0], [2, 0], [2, 2], [0, 2]])

poly.contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2)]))
Out[3]: False

poly.contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2), Point(1,1)]))
Out[4]: True

poly.contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2), Point(1,1), Point(3,3)]))
Out[5]: False
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Citing the [docs on `object.contains(other)`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.contains):

> Returns `True` if no points of `other` lie in the exterior of the `object` and at least one point of the interior of `other` lies in the interior of `object`.

So, in fact, everything works as intended.

1) When you check `poly.contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2)]))`, the point doesn't lie in the interior of `poly` but on its boundary. Therefore it returns `False`.

2) When you check `poly.contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2), Point(1,1)]))`, no points of the `MultiPoint` object lie in the exterior of `poly` and there is one point that lies in its interior. This satisfies the given conditions.

3) For `poly.contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2), Point(1,1), Point(3,3)]))` case there is one point that lies in the exterior of `poly`, hence the `False` as a result.

---

P.S.: You wrote in the comment:

> Regarding 2) the point `Point(2,2)` lies in the exterior of poly, i.e. `poly.exterior.contains(Point(2,2))` returns `True`.

This `exterior` attribute of a polygon actually means the exterior `LinearRing` of a polygon. And it is not equal to the exterior points set. [Docs on `Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#Polygon) say:

> Component rings are accessed via `exterior` and `interiors` properties.

The interior, boundary, and exterior points sets are defined [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#spatial-data-model) as follows:

> A Surface has an interior set consisting of the infinitely many points within (imagine a Curve dragged in space to cover an area), a boundary set consisting of one or more Curves, and an exterior set of all other points including those within holes that might exist in the surface.

Comment: Regarding 2) the point Point(2,2) lies in the exterior of poly, i.e. poly.exterior.contains(Point(2,2)) returns True

Comment: @Michael I understand the confusion. There is some collision in definitions. I updated the answer.

Comment: yes, there is a collision in definitions. The attribute should be called "boundary" instead of "exterior" in accordance with the definition. The behaviour is counter-intuitive though. If `poly.contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2), Point(1,1)]))` returns `True` and `MultiPoint([Point(2,2), Point(1,1)]).contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2)]))` returns `True` then `poly.contains(MultiPoint([Point(2,2)]))` should return `True` as well.

Comment: [`boundary`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.boundary) attribute already exists for polygons. `exterior_ring` would be a better choice IMHO. And about the behaviour for multipoints, it comes from the [fact that "*A Point has an interior set of exactly one point*"](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#spatial-data-model).

Comment: What shapely means by `object.exterior` and `object.interiors` are different parts of the boundary, property names based on "external boundary" and "internal boundaries" would be better. IMHO, a single point on the boundary of a polygon should be contained in the polygon. It does intersect with the polygon. It should be true that "A contains B and B contains C implies A contains C".

Comment: Here are a few more links about that:
http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html
https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/519
https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/290